# Remove all label elements from JQuery variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the following:

```
var transferTemplate = $('#transfersRow').html();
```

in order to store some html code in a variable, which results to:

```
<div class="form-group row">

     <div class="col-lg-4">
         <label for="inc[1].a">Counterparty</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inc[1].a" 
                name="inc[1].a" placeholder="Enter Counterparty">
     </div>

</div>
```

Now I would like to be able to remove all labels from the html code. I tried:

```
$(transferTemplate).find(label).remove();

$(transferTemplate).remove('label');

$(transferTemplate).filter('label').remove();
```

but none works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns a string representation of the HTML:

```
var transferTemplate = $('#transfersRow').html();
```

You could remove the label from this string like this:

```
$(transferTemplate).find('label').remove();
```

However, all that does it create a *new* jQuery object with the HTML minus the label.  It won't update the `transferTemplate` variable.

Instead, you could assign `$(transferTemplate)` to a new variable.

That would allow you to remove the label and still have access to the updated HTML.

**Snippet**

```js
var transferTemplate = $('#transfersRow').html(),
    template = $(transferTemplate);

template.find('label').remove();

$('textarea').val(template.html());
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="transfersRow">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <label for="inc[1].a">Counterparty</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inc[1].a" name="inc[1].a" placeholder="Enter Counterparty">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<strong>Output</strong>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: why I had to assign it in a new variable first?

Comment: My post assumes you don't want to update the DOM, but that you want to update the HTML string instead.  Let me know if that's not the case.

Comment: Yes that's the case. Afterwards, I use append to append it back as a new row.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to select the row that you want to remove labels at each row:

Like this:

```
$(".row").each(function( index ) {
   $(this).find("label").remove(); //find label at each row and remove.
});
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are misunderstanding the result of html(). It doesn't return a Jquery DOM object. The result is just a string representation. Just remove the .html() and I'm sure you will be able to call the functions you want.

```
var transferTemplate = $('#transfersRow');
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess the correct way is: `$(transferTemplate).find('label').remove();`

https://api.jquery.com/remove/
Like the penultimate example...

Comment: But it returns all remove elements instead of the html without the elements

Comment: So,

var template = $(transferTemplate).find('label').remove();
$('#newTemplate').html(template);

And in HTML: <div id="newTemplate"></div>